# Как изменить структуру обьекта JS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

У меня есть такой обьект:

```
const obj = {
  'id1': {
    name: 'test',
    type: 'text'
  },
  'id2': {
    name: 'test2',
    type: 'number'
  },
}
```

Как его можно преобразовать в такой:

```
const obj = {
  'test': 'test',
  'test2': 'test2'
}
```

Comment: по какому правилу нужно преобразовывать?

Comment: @Grundy мне просто приходит обьект в одном виде а передавать дальше его нужно в другом. Я не совсем понял вопрос, сори

Comment: вопрос: как из одного вида переделать в другой? то есть, почему для type:text и type:number - должен быть один и тот же выход?

Comment: @Grundy мне нужно получить только имя , а все остальные свойства откинуть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const obj = {
  'id1': {
    name: 'test',
    type: 'text'
  },
  'id2': {
    name: 'test2',
    type: 'number'
  },
};

function convert(obj) {
  const res = {};
  for (let id in obj) {
    const name = obj[id].name;
    res[name] = name;
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(convert(obj));
```

Comment: А если у меня вместо прошлой структуры такая const obj = [
  {
    name: 'test',
    type: 'text'
  },
  {
    name: 'test2',
    type: 'number'
  },
]

Comment: @dev_jun ничего не поменяется